# Are Django's generic class views actually used?

Tags: django

I have discovered Django's generic class views now when I'm in the middle of my first Django project. 
I didn't know that there are class based views or generic views.
I have made my own class views but now I'm thinking of refactoring. The only problem is I don't like these Django built-in views. I don't like putting stuff in the urls.py, my own views call sometimes each-other (they don't return a result, just add to the context)...

Anyway, I'm curios what others are doing? Are Django's built-in generic views actually used in real life?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mixins are a good way of using generic class based views.

[here](http://lukeplant.me.uk/blog/posts/djangos-cbvs-were-a-mistake/) is a good comparison of the advantages and disadvantages of class based views